# How to escape characters in string variables? (cmd commands)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cmd, escaping

I have a list of cmd commands I need to run:

```
sc config winmgmt start= demand
net stop winmgmt /y
rd /S /Q %windir%\\system32\\wbem\\repository
rd /S /Q %windir%\\syswow64\\wbem\\repository
C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msiexec.exe /unregserver
C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msiexec.exe /regserver
regsvr32 /s C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\scecli.dll
regsvr32 /s C:\\WINDOWS\\syswow64\\scecli.dll
for %i in (C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\wbem\\*.dll) do RegSvr32 -s %i
mofcomp C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\wbem\\rsop.mof
mofcomp C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\wbem\\en-US\\rsop.mfl
for %i in (C:\\WINDOWS\\syswow64\\wbem\\*.mof) do mofcomp %i
mofcomp.exe C:\\Windows\\system32\\WBEM\\win32_encryptablevolume.mof
sc config winmgmt start= auto
net start winmgmt
```

I have a txt file in `Properties.Resources` containing the above commands. And I try to run them like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

if (process != null)
{
    foreach(var myString in File.ReadAllLines(Properties.Resources.commandsTXT))
    {
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(myString);
    }
    process.StandardInput.Close();
}
```

The problem is when I try to run it, I get `Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.` How could I possibly escape every character in it? As you can see I already tried replacing `\`s to `\\`s, but no luck

Comment: Instead of `myString = "\\"` use `myString=@"\"`. Also, intead of new row use `"\n \r"`.

Comment: But how? I set `myString` in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Then just use `@` character before your string, for example instead of `"mofcomp.exe C:\\Windows\\system32\\WBEM\\win32_encryptablevolume.mof"` just write `@"mofcomp.exe C:\Windows\system32\WBEM\win32_encryptablevolume.mof"`.

Comment: So basically just put every line between `@"` and `"`?

Comment: Tried it, but same error.

Comment: It depends on how you load these commands. If you load it from a text file and use command `foreach` then in text file just replace \\ with \ (because when it is loaded it will be automatically escaped).

Comment: No, they won't. That was the first thing to try, I mean with `\`s. And beacause of they failed I tried to escape them.